# Format compose output

Tags: arrays, json, power-automate

Hi I am trying to create a json object to  return under one value, however when I attempt this additional formatting is added which makes it appear as though power automate is attempting to convert it to a string. HAs any one got any ideas?

Compose 1 (Output is what I want):

[image]

Compose 2 (Output has additional quotation marks and slashes):

[image]

Any ideas how to address the formatting issues in the second compose? If I try and put the values directly in the second compose I receive json errors.

Thanks in advance.

I have tried various solutions such as converting to json, joining, selecting to no avail.

Comment: You’re right, the inner json is serialized into a string and stored as a value in the outer json, it’s not a formatting issue, it’s just how the json has been structured. Rather than show us the screenshots, can you paste an example of both the input and expected output in json to your question? Bottom line, you’ll need to do the work to extract those values as json, it’s not magic, it won’t just do it for you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me. I resolved this by amending my select statements and removing the initial compose action.